# toggleClass on label with checkbox within

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a class using toggleClass to a label when the label is clicked. The trouble I am having is that when I put a checkbox in it, the class only gets added when you click on the checkbox itself and not the text. How can I make it so that it adds the class when the text is clicked as well?

http://jsfiddle.net/p8erw/1/

Here is the code I'm using

```
$("label").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of binding to the labels click event, try binding to the checkbox's change event:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function () {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p8erw/4/

Comment: You got it right first haha. Thanks so much. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `click()` function to `on change` event. :)

```
 $("label").on('change',function() {
       $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
 });
```

Comment: You got it right too.. but he got it right first. Thanks so much :D